# Correct way to handle failed request - python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests library in python.

```
def get_response(url):
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)  
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)                  
        response = session.get(url)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"{str(e)}")

def get_soup(html):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        return soup 
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"{str(e)}")
```

I am using `get_response` function to make requests. When server is up, try block return me the response and I use it in further code... but when server is down, except block returns None and my whole code fails after that.

How can I handle this situation, the whole code relies on the response.. like response.text, response.status_code etc.

for example:

```
response = get_response(some_url)
html = response.text
soup = get_soup(html)
```

so when actual response is received from try block... the code works fine after that.
but in case, lets assume server is down, so except block will run and return None (here I am not returning explicitly).
So this `html = response.text` will fail saying `NoneType has no attribute text`

Answer (score 0):

I Will implement the program this way.

```
def get_response(url):
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        response = session.get(url)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"{str(e)}")


def get_soup(html):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        return soup
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"{str(e)}")


response = get_response(some_url)
if response:
    html = response.text
    soup = get_soup(html)
else:
    print('Error: Some error message')
```

At if block if the response value is None than the else statement will run.

Comment: I don't write return None usually when I don't have to return anything specific because None is returned when we don't mention anything. My concern is how to handle this except block so further code can run smoothly. None causes problem in further code.

Comment: Can u add further code so I can see how you are using this function. Without knowledge of how you are using this function, it will be very difficult to find a solution.

Comment: I added some additional code... please check.

Comment: @HemantSah No, please add the code in your question.

Comment: @HemantSah add code so we can see how are you using this function.

Comment: I added some code further. check  please